# Immovable alert window

Tags: java, javafx, alert

I'm trying to stop the users from being able to move an alert that pops up. I have found one option is to set the style to `UNDECORATED` to remove the border which they would click on to move the alert, but I personally think this looks very ugly.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Sounds like very bad user experience to me.

Comment: I'm not positive but in theory you could probably swallow the drag and drop events associated with the pop up window by overriding the window's event listener. Basically create a class that extends whatever the window class is, override the event listener method(s) and check for drag-drop events, returning if they occur and calling `super(...)` if they don't. And don't set the style to `UNDECORATED`.

Comment: I didn't say you did. Still, it's always worth questioning where requirements have come from and why they exist. If you assume that no thought has been put in to requirements, you'll probably be right more often than not. Depressing, really.

Comment: Wow Michael, your profile says 24 and already so cynical, it's going to be a long career :-)  Not that you're wrong ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest going with `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` and adding any decoration you want inside.

Not having system decoration, in this case, is a **benefit**. Because people are used to standard controls (close button, moving by dragging title, etc) and by removing them you give a clear sign that you don't want this windows to be movable.

Small example:

```
   Stage alert = new Stage(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
   alert.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
   VBox root = new VBox(30);
   root.setStyle("-fx-background-color: antiquewhite");
   root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
   root.setPadding(new Insets(25));
   root.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.BLACK, 
        BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, CornerRadii.EMPTY, BorderWidths.DEFAULT)));

   Button btn = new Button("Got it!");
   btn.setOnAction((e)-> {alert.close();});
   Label label = new Label("Alert!");
   label.setFont(Font.font("Verdana", 20));
   root.getChildren().addAll(label, btn);

   alert.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 150));
```

which gives you next window:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution! My problem is still that I personally find "undecorated" windows jarring and ugly. I've tried adding borders to them but nothing seems to stop me wanting to claw my eyes out when I see one.